# How to display utf-8 characters like alpha and beta in OpenSceneGraph or osg

Tags: c++, utf-8, openscenegraph, osgeo

I need to display `UTF-8` characters in `osg`, however `text->setText( test,osgText::String::ENCODING_UTF8 );` cannot display though, it's like `?` in the scene. Does anybody have the same problem or know how to do it?

Code Snippet

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Geode> geode = new osg::Geode;
{
    osg::ref_ptr<osgText::Text> text = new osgText::Text; 
    text->setFont( "CAMBRIA.TTC" );
    //text->setFont( font.get() );
    text->setColor( white );
    text->setCharacterSize( characterSize );
    text->setPosition( OsgFunc::arrowArcTextPosition( centerPoint, centerPoint + osg::Vec3( -30, 0, 0 ), centerPoint + v ) + osg::Vec3d( 0, -5, 1 ) );
    text->setAxisAlignment( osgText::Text::SCREEN );
    text->setText( "\u03b2",osgText::String::ENCODING_UTF8 );
    geode->addDrawable( text.get() );
}
```

Comment: You need to use a font which has those characters in it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already checked this! I used this guy 'text->setFont( "CAMBRIA.TTC" )'; But it still cannot work.

Comment: **Post your code.** Perhaps the font is not being found? (e.g. if your font path is not set up).

Comment: I even copied the font file into the release folder, still cannot work@Ben, the original code is too long, I edited the question and added some code, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the UTF-8 escape is supported by your compiler? Have you tried encoding it as `"\xCE\xB2"`??

Comment: Actually I think you just haven't told the compiler it is a UTF-8 string literal:  `text->setText(u"\u03b2",osgText::String::ENCODING_UTF8 );`... You told `setText` but the compiler also needs to be told so it can interpret the `\u` correctly. Also you need C++11 support for this.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I use VS2008 for this project!It is a legacy project that I maintain now. It uses Qt also. Do you think I can do something about it by using VS2008? People say that VS2008 cannot support c++11, I will test it when I go to lab. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben ! It works now! Many many thanks to you! Also don't worry about C++11, VS2008 works!